# I want to convert MFC .exe to DLL which should work on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, dll, activex

I have created application which is opening .txt files in an window. I want to make it as Active X which should work on IE.

What should i do to convert to DLL.

Please suggests.

Sow

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, there's nothing like "converting an mfc executable to an activex". You can create an activex project from scratch and port your mfc codes to your activex project (possibly with some modification), build it and then get the dll.

Answer (score 0):

There was a MIND article about this very topic entitled "Designing ActiveX Components with the MFC Document/View Model" here: http://www.microsoft.com/mind/0497/mfc.asp but that link no longer works.

A quick Google found a copy of the article here: http://blog.csdn.net/l12345678/archive/2007/07/27/1711521.aspx